# Taylor expansion of distance along geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

On a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ without boundary, let $x,y\in M$ and $u\in T_xM, v\in T_yM$ be fixed. Let $\gamma_1$ be the geodesic starting at $x$ with initial velocity $u$ and $\gamma_2$ be the geodesic starting at $y$ with initial velocity $v$. I am looking for a Taylor expansion of $d^2(\gamma_0(t),\gamma_1(t))$ around $t=0$, where $d$ is the Riemannian distance.
When $x=y$, it is fairly easy, using Jacobi fields that have a simple expression. When $x\neq y$, I am having some trouble. I am mostly curious to see what the first terms should depend on.
Thanks!

Comment: You can still use a Jacobi field. Differentiate the family of minimal geodesics joining $\gamma_0(t)$ to $\gamma_1(t)$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: Sure, but when $x=y$, you heavily use the fact that the geodesic $\eta(\cdot,t)$ joining $\gamma_0(t)$ and $\gamma_1(t)$ is constant at $t=0$, yielding a grasp on the derivatives at $t=0$ of $\eta(s,t)$ with respect to $t$ and $s$. When $x\neq y$, I don't really see what to do, but I may be missing something. Could you please elaborate?